# event.addEventListener() in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, loops, dom, events, foreach

```
function initNumberElement(){
let idReference = ['zero','one','two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
let numberElementReference = [];
let temp = '0';

for (const key of idReference) {
    numberElementReference.push(document.getElementById(key));
    for (let i = 0; i < numberElementReference.length; i++) {
        numberElementReference[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            temp = temp + String(i);
            changeVisualOut(temp)
        })
    }
}
return numberElementReference;
```

}

Once the elements have been retrieved from the Dom I am trying to dynamically insert an addEventListener () for each element with forEach () but every time I click on an element the event is triggered several times. Why?

Even using a for loop the dynamics remain the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need second loop at all. In first loop you are iterating through id list and add elements into **numberElementReference** array.
Then for all elements in **numberElementReference** array you are adding click handler, thats why you got multiple listeners per element (because for each item in outer loop you are registering event listeners for the whole **numberElementReference** array again)

You can just use one loop:

```
function initNumberElement() {
  let idReference = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"];
  let numberElementReference = [];
  let temp = "0";

  for (let i = 0; i < idReference.length; i++) {
    const id = idReference[i];
    const element = document.getElementById(id);

    numberElementReference.push(element);

    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
      temp = temp + String(i);
      changeVisualOut(temp);
    });

  }

  return numberElementReference;

}
```